# How to write Videos in Documents?

Tags: iphone, ios

i have problem regarding in writing videos in App documents directory. It's not visible when go manually to check on that location. But when you use FileManager to check,it exist.

Comment: Please provide some code

Comment: Check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16412289/how-to-retrieve-video-from-bundle-and-add-it-to-document-directory/16412348#16412348

Answer (score 1):

This code is work for me, check this code and try:

```
NSString *fileName = nil;
NSData *dataToSave = nil;

fileName = @"/myVideo.mov";
dataToSave = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:self.urlVideo];


NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

BOOL isSuccess = [dataToSave writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:NO];

NSLog(@"result : %@",[NSNumber numberWithBool:isSuccess]);
```

Comment: i got the answer..thanx for giving this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Writing videos in documents folder is just like writing any other file. just do:

```
[data writeToFile:filePath];
```

And to check it manually, you have to go to this path:

```
/Users/LoginName/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/6B0A776-4D3D-4250-8FD2-892E7BBC1E9/Documents/
```

if you are checking for simulator iOS 6.1.

Are you sure you are going the right way?